# std::vector not exception-safe?

Tags: c++, vector

I've heard it mentioned a couple of times that `std::vector` is not exception-safe when storing raw pointers and that one should use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead.

My question is, why is `std::vector` not exception-safe and how do these classes fix that?

Comment: Do **not** use `std::auto_ptr<>` in standard collection classes. `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>` are safe, but no smart pointer in the C++03 standard library is.

Comment: Exception safety does not depend on what the vector stores.

Comment: @ildjarn I think that's what I meant to say, I can't seem to find where I saw the mention so I can't double check. I edited the question anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `std::vector` that's not exception safe, it's using raw pointers for memory management:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        int* i = new int;

        throw "oops, memory leak!";
    }
    catch (...){}
}
```

That has nothing to do with vector's per se, it's just that doing this is the exact same problem:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::vector<int*> vi;
        vi.push_back(new int);

        throw "oops, memory leak!";
    }
    catch (...){}
}
```

Both of these are fixed by using smart pointers:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int> i(new int);

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vi;
        vi.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));
        vi.push_back(std::move(i));

        throw "vector destroys unique_ptr's...which delete their memory";
    }
    catch (...){}
}
```

(Or `shared_ptr`, which is more expensive. You may also use pointer containers, from Boost.)

Comment: This is likely the case.  Good call.

Answer (score 2):

By "not exception safe" I presume they mean there will be a memory leak if the vector is destroyed by the unwinding during an exception.

Shared_ptr makes sure the objects pointed to by the pointers are deleted when the vector itself is destroyed.

Another alternative is the [Boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/libs/ptr_container/).